# Objects in layers on ARToolKit i nUnity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I'm starting to develop a game in Unity for Android using ARToolKit 5. I know that version 6 is already released but I had some problems when installing that version but anyway version 5 works fine. 
My problem is that when I place an object on the AR Background layer it will be shown when marker is detected but I'm unable to show some static objects that should be visible everytime and not only when the marker "enter" in the scene.
Any suggestion on this???
Thanx in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to show content that is unrelated to the marker tracking? If so, how should the app know where to show it?

Comment: I place my objects in a specific position in the Unity editor. I assume that those objects should stay in their position regardless the marker position. But I found that every objects move together the object set to show at the marker position. If I change the layer of these objects then doesn't show at all.